# Insertar en una tabla el resultado de un procedimiento almacenado SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure, insert, sql-server-management

queria pedir su ayuda con un procedimiento almacenado que realice en sql server 2016 el cual basicamente solo es una consulta que me devuelve el siguiente resultado:

[image: Resultado SP]

Ahora como dije en mi pregunta me gustaria saber como insertar este resultado de mi SP en una tabla que cree en mi base de datos, la tabla que cree tiene los mismos campos que el resultado es decir id, C, E, NA, y porcentaje.
Este es mi SP:

```
create or alter procedure sp_calificaciones
  as
    begin
        SELECT id,  ( c * 100.)  / SUM( c + e + na) AS 'C',
            ( e * 100.)  / SUM( c + e + na) AS 'E',
            ( na * 100.) / SUM( c + e + na) AS 'NA',
            ( SUM(c+e+na)*100.) / SUM( c + e + na) AS 'porcentaje' --Esto siempre será 100
        FROM prueba
        GROUP BY id, c, e, na
    end
  go
```

Y quiero depositarlos en la tabla calificaciones que tiene esta estructura:

```
create table [dbo].[Calificaciones](
id int not null,
C int null,
E int null,
NA int null,
Porcentaje int null
)
```

Bueno mil gracias por su apoyo.

Comment: Hola! Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para repasar el uso del sitio. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.
No hay ningún dato del procedimiento que mencionas y que quieres que ahora inserte; tampoco sabemos en qué tabla ni con qué tipos de dato trabajas.

Comment: @Alfabravo Listo amigo! los acabe de agregar tanto el sp y la estructura de la tabla donde quiero depositar el resultado del sp

Comment: Evita usar el prefijo `sp_` en los nombres de tus objetos. Este prefijo se usa para los objetos especiales del sistema en SQL Server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo más simple, a es hacer un `INSERT INTO TABLA (..) EXECUTE SP`, en tu caso algo así:

```
INSERT INTO Calificaciones (id, C, E, NA, Porcentaje)
EXECUTE sp_calificaciones
```

Si bien es lo más cómodo y en tu ejemplo creo que es lo mejor, puede que tengas algún problema cuando anides más de un insert de este tipo, si llegara a ocurrir esto y tuvieras algún error del servidor, la alternativa sería transformar el `sp` de consulta en uno de inserción:

```
create or alter procedure sp_calificaciones
  as
    begin
        INSERT INTO Calificaciones (id, C, E, NA, Porcentaje)
        SELECT id,  ( c * 100.)  / SUM( c + e + na) AS 'C',
            ( e * 100.)  / SUM( c + e + na) AS 'E',
            ( na * 100.) / SUM( c + e + na) AS 'NA',
            ( SUM(c+e+na)*100.) / SUM( c + e + na) AS 'porcentaje' --Esto siempre será 100
        FROM prueba
        GROUP BY id, c, e, na
    end
```